# MacBook display issue with garbled screen. What happened?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

While I was working, my MacBook screen unexpectedly displayed an unusual appearance as shown in the attached picture.

I am not sure what should be done.

I tried restarting my laptop and it is still the same. Please help.

[image]

Comment: You don't mention the specific model you have, but this looks like a hardware issue.

Comment: Its : MacOS Monterey, Macbook Air ( 13-inch, early 2015) Processor : 1.6 GHz Dual Core Intel Core i5

Comment: Yes, this looks like a classic graphics hardware failure. Sadly all too common in iMacs and MacBooks once they get a bit old.

Comment: Hi benwiggy, I'm a bit confused now, not sure how much it gonna cost to repair my laptop.  I am unsure whether it is more beneficial to get it repaired or consider purchasing a new MacBook instead. Any advice please?

Comment: You can take it to an Apple Store and see if Apple will repair it, though it is classed as "Vintage".

Answer (score 0):

Run the `Use Apple Diagnostics to test your Mac`

Described in details here

[apple test][1]

To start it depends on type of your Mac, for Intel CPU use the **Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold the D key on your keyboard as your Mac starts up**.

It should tell you if. you have hardware or sotware problem

Once you have the result come back and report it, we might be able to help further

If hardware test shows no problems lets do the Software test

Start up your Intel-based Mac in safe mode

Turn on or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key until you see the login window.
Log in to your Mac.

You might be asked to log in again.

On either the first or second login window, you should see “Safe Boot” in the menu bar.

.
[1]: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102550

Comment: Hey Ruskes, I've run the test and I have got no issues found. reference code :ADP000.

Comment: @Rai ok that was the Hardware test, lets now do the software test Start up your Intel-based Mac in safe mode
Turn on or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key until you see the login window.
Log in to your Mac.
You might be asked to log in again.
On either the first or second login window, you should see “Safe Boot” in the menu bar.